# Python: import URLs into list

Tags: python, list, url

I am trying to make a python script that can download subtitles for *How I Met Your Mother* from subscene.com.
I am new to Python and programming.

I would like the search result to be put in a list, which is printed afterwards, so that the user can choose the right URL. The problem is that I don't know how create a list from the search result. Does anyone know how to do this?

Here is what I've made so far:

```
import urllib

class Subtitle_downloader(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.SearchCriteria = ['How.I.Met.Your.Mother']
        self.Episode = str(raw_input('Enter episode: '))
        self.Carateristics = str(raw_input('Enter caracteristics: ')) #'HDTV' for an example
        self.SearchCriteria.append('S07E'+self.Episode)
        self.SearchCriteria.append(self.Carateristics)
        print self.SearchCriteria

    def SubDL(self, SubUrl):
        self.AllSubs = urllib.urlopen(SubUrl).readlines()
        for item in self.AllSubs:
            if self.SearchCriteria[0] and self.SearchCriteria[1] in item:
            #Create a list

t=Subtitle_downloader()
t.SubDL('http://subscene.com/How-I-Met-Your-Mother-Seventh-Season/subtitles-90698.aspx')
```

Comment: Check the logic ... do you really want if self.SearchCriteria[0] and self.SearchCriteria[1] in item? That will check if SearchCriteria[0] is True, not if it's in item.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

```
def SubDL(self, SubUrl):

    l = [item for item in urllib.urlopen(SubUrl).readlines()
         if self.SearchCriteria[0] in item and self.SearchCriteria[1] in item]
    for item in l:
        print('An item: {}'.format(item))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t want to use list comprehension (which might look a bit complicated), you can also simply create an empty list, and append items to it:

```
def SubDL(self, SubUrl):
    subList = []
    self.AllSubs = urllib.urlopen(SubUrl).readlines()
    for item in self.AllSubs:
        if self.SearchCriteria[0] and self.SearchCriteria[1] in item:
           subList.append(item)
    return subList
```

Comment: Thanks both are answers are very helpful.

But i am facing a new problem:
Is it possible to get python to print out the hyperlinks the same way they are shown on subscene?

Comment: See edit to my response. Format however you want using string formatting.